# index field property setting through JAVA API for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Can i have a sample code for assigning the properties to index fields (as in config.xml in case of solr), for elasticsearch. Java API code sample for loading the property file, as well.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();
        Client client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300));
        List<XYZ> list = xyz.getObj("5");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        for(Object obj : list){
            try {

                String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
                System.out.println(json);

 //I want a code here to load the mapping file and syntax for mapping file,
   through which i can say that only few attributes of this object should be indexed   and rest all to be stored..//                

                IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder = client.prepareIndex("searchindex", "searchtype", obj.getId());
                indexRequestBuilder.setSource(json);
                indexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: post your code , so far..

Comment: Can you go through and provide any help.. I have edited my post..